# BUG - Media queries CSS en dispositivos iOS

Tags: css, ios, responsive, google-chrome, safari

Estoy teniendo problemas con mis media queries en dispositivos iOS.
Hasta el momento lo he probado con mi iPad Air 2 (Chrome para iOS) y en un iPhone 12 Pro (Safaru en simulador Xcode)

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1aNMcbX73dEDlokOhm2XPBkEjxCH_2iINBV3BbAT9-q4/edit?usp=sharing

La primera diapositiva muestra como se ve mi sitio por defecto al abrir Chrome en el iPad (vista móvil por defecto). Como se aprecia, toma las media queries de un teléfono, en lugar de las de 1020px que establecí previamente.

La segunda diapositiva es como se ve después de solicitar la versión de escritorio; como se debería ver en Chrome.

La tercera diapositiva muestra como se ve correctamente en mi teléfono Android y cómo se ve en un iPhone.

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Aún escribiendo esto en mi HTML, nada cambia.

El código fuente en caso de ser de utilidad.

https://github.com/erickcm2k/newProjectPortfolio/tree/master/portfolio

Comment: Listo. Gracias por la observación.

Answer (score 0):

Update

Esta es la ruta a mi CSS reset, importado de internet.

https://github.com/erickcm2k/newProjectPortfolio/blob/master/portfolio/src/Containers/reset.css

Todo se corrigió al comentar la línea de en medio línea:

```
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 62.5%; /* Línea 205 */
```